# Convert Java Collection.toArray to kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Please help me convert this java code to kotlin, I try many times but I can't

```
ObjectStream<DocumentSample> bin 
    = ObjectStreamUtils.createObjectStream(categoryStreams.toArray(new ObjectStream[0]));
```

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-A in your Java source file, in IntelliJ (Cmd-shift-A on Mac), then type "convert Java file to Kotlin".

Comment: Does the original Java code work?

Comment: What is categoryStreams defined as?

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, you may use `toTypedArray()` to get an `Array` from a `List`:

```
categoryStreams.toTypedArray()    //Array<ObjectStream<DocumentSample>>
```

Then, you can use spread operator to prefix the array and pass it to `ObjectStreamUtils.createObjectStream()`:

```
val bin = ObjectStreamUtils.createObjectStream<DocumentSample>(*categoryStreams.toTypedArray())
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the categoryStreams object is one of the `Collection` type(List, Set, etc.), you can call kotlin's extension method `toTypedArray` on it to get an array of the `ObjectStream`:

This should work:

```
val bin = ObjectStreamUtils.createObjectStream(categoryStreams.toTypedArray())
```

If the method accepts vararg of ObjectStream, then you can use spread operator `*` to spread array to vararg:

```
val bin = ObjectStreamUtils.createObjectStream(*categoryStreams.toTypedArray())
```

Comment: i tried, this is java code:
https://github.com/mlehman/nlp-intent-toolkit/blob/master/src/main/java/nlp/intent/toolkit/IntentTrainer.java

Comment: Your code compiles, and is more accurate to the intent of the original java code, even though it is not a literal translation.  This may be the best answer if the OP can be a little more informative about his problem.

Answer (score 0):

**To convert Java file to Kotlin**

1. On the main menu, point to Code menu.
2. Choose Convert Java File to Kotlin File.
3. Done.

In your case it converts to:

```
val bin = ObjectStreamUtils.createObjectStream(categoryStreams.toArray(arrayOfNulls<ObjectStream>(0)))
```

Comment: Error:(44, 109) Kotlin: One type argument expected for interface ObjectStream<T : Any!> : AutoCloseable defined in opennlp.tools.util

Comment: And why didn't you include this in your question?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a type inference problem.  Try the code below.  I add the declaration for `categoryStreams`.  Not sure how it is declared in your code.  But this is a reasonable declaration from looking at the code on github.

```
val categoryStreams = arrayListOf<ObjectStream<DocumentSample>>()
val bin = ObjectStreamUtils.createObjectStream(categoryStreams.toArray(arrayOfNulls<ObjectStream<DocumentSample>>(0)))
```

The idea is to provide the correct type for inference (which the converter neglected to provide).  The original java did not infer the type, it was an explicit cast.

Comment: This is java code : https://github.com/mlehman/nlp-intent-toolkit/blob/master/src/main/java/nlp/intent/toolkit/IntentTrainer.java

Comment: @bitsugar - who are you asking?  The example I provide in my answer compiles when I include the org.apache.opennlp.tools library and declare the variable categoryStreams as an ArrayList (I've updated my answer to show the declaration).  The OP has not shown how he declares categoryStreams (presumably he converted java to kotlin).

Answer (score 0):

var bin = ObjectStreamUtils.createObjectStream(categoryStreams.toArray(arrayOfNulls(0)))

the above code is converted your code to kotlin.

Comment: That may be how the Kotlin converter makes the conversion, but it does not compile.  "Type inference failed.  Not enough information to infer parameter T in ..."